# n + 1 issue when ordering by child's attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

The following query suffers from the 'n+1' problem of loading each order for each record:

```
Job.joins('LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.job_id = jobs.id').order("orders.featured")
```

Same for this:

```
Job.includes(:order).order("orders.featured")
```

Removing the .order(...) part removes the n + 1 issue, but then it's not ordered. Any ideas how to fix this? Do I need to create a column in the parent for the 'featured' attribute?

Output:

```
  Order Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."job_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["job_id", 26]]
  Rendered jobs/_job.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Order Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."job_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["job_id", 3]]
  Rendered jobs/_job.html.erb (2.0ms)
  Order Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."job_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["job_id", 52]]
  Rendered jobs/_job.html.erb (1.7ms)
  Order Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."job_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["job_id", 13]]
  Rendered jobs/_job.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Order Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."job_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["job_id", 34]]
  Rendered jobs/_job.html.erb (1.9ms)
  Order Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."job_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["job_id", 64]]
  Rendered jobs/_job.html.erb (2.8ms)
  Order Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."job_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["job_id", 94]]
  Rendered jobs/_job.html.erb (3.2ms)
  Order Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."job_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["job_id", 60]]
  Rendered jobs/_job.html.erb (3.1ms)
  Order Load (0.4ms)  SELECT  "orders".* FROM "orders" WHERE "orders"."job_id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["job_id", 29]]
```

Comment: Does Job have_many Orders?

Comment: Show the code in `jobs/_job.html.erb` as well as your `Job` model code.

Answer (score 0):

Try using preload for the associated data:

```
Job.joins('LEFT JOIN orders ON orders.job_id = jobs.id')
  .order("orders.featured")
  .preload(:orders)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Job.includes(:order).order("orders.featured")
```

Includes doesn't join the tables together until you call it in the view.  It will actually do 2 queries.  If you want the 2 tables to be joined to do the order, you need to use eager_load:

```
Job.eager_load(:order).order("orders.featured")
```

http://blog.bigbinary.com/2013/07/01/preload-vs-eager-load-vs-joins-vs-includes.html